# How do I make specific Tiles not accessible using pygame

Tags: tiled, tmx

Im Currently trying to create a 2d game (similar to old zelda or pokemon) using Pygame where you have to solve a few little quests. Im currently at a point where i have a map, player model, movement etc.. But now i need to make some parts of my map not accesible to my player. But i cant find anything on how to do it.

I know that i need to use pytmx to get the tile propersties and that i have to change something with the properties in tiled itdelf but i cant seem to find anything thats working.